# Migrating Contacts from Joomla to Drupal

Tags: nodes, migrations

The Joomla module in Drupal does a good job on migrating content and users, but it doesn't have functionality to pull the contacts from Joomla.

Has anyone successfully migrated contacts from Joomla to Drupal? What methods are there of accomplishing this?

I started to manually move the contacts... but there are about 100 of them =/. I started by creating a new content type with the fields for the contact, and am using the Views module to create a table for the contacts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Used phpmyadmin to dump the data from the table containing the content I needed, and put it into a CSV file. Then I used Drupal's Feeds module to import the CSV into the content type that I created.

Worked beautifully.